# sh - Build string containing paths

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I'm building a small shell script for finding cat/man pages on a wide range of unix systems... in bash, I could build all possible paths by doing this:

```
# default search paths
default=$(echo /usr/{share, local, dpkg, XR11}/man/{man, cat}{1..8})

for path in $default
do 
  ...
done
```

Unfortunately, I'm forced to use sh... I could build the paths with loops, but this would look really ugly... is there a neater/shorter way?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sh'? The original bourne shell hasn't been around for a while. Exactly what shell have you got there?

Comment: @bmargulies: waddya mean?  It (Bourne shell) is still standard on Unix (AIX, HP-UX, Solaris).  Not on MacOS X or Linux, for sure, and other shells are available on AIX, HP-UX, Solaris.  But Bourne shell is still standard in places.

Comment: It's for a university project... the script should be able to work on as much unix systems possible, so the decision was to use sh for greater backwars-compatibility

Comment: BTW, Bash wouldn't be happy with the spaces in your brace expansion.

Comment: @bmargulies: `ash`, `sash`, the `sh` compatibility mode in `bash` (try invoking it as `/bin/sh` and see what you get), the shell in busybox, etc. etc. etc. Plain vanilla Bourne shell is still the safest default for scripting.

Answer (score 2):

On my Linux system, "man -w" prints the location of the nroff source file instead of its contents. That way you use man's internal search to find the files - just like a user on the command line.

See "man man" for more information.

Comment: That works fine as long as there's nowhere that 'man' doesn't know about that you need it to look.  Then you start playing with MANPATH.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't terrible:

```
for dir in share local pdkg XR11; do
  for type in man cat; do
    for n in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do
      path="/usr/${dir}/man/${type}$n"
      # ...
    done
  done
done
```

or even, though it's not DRY, this is explicit and readable

```
prefixes="
    /usr/share/man/man /usr/share/man/cat
    /usr/local/man/man /usr/local/man/cat
    /usr/pdkg/man/man  /usr/pdkg/man/cat
    /usr/XR11/man/man  /usr/XR11/man/cat
"
for prefix in $prefixes; do
  for n in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do
    path="${prefix}$n"
    # ...
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use find

```
find /usr/share /usr/local /usr/dpkg /usr/XR11 -type d \( -name "man[0-9]" -o -name "cat[0-9]" -o -name "cat" -o -name "man" \)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given Bourne shell, I'd probably use:

```
for path in `ls -d /usr/*/man/[mc]a[tn][1-8]`
do 
    if [ -d $path ]
    then ...
    fi
done
```

This only leads you astray if somebody malicious creates a directory `/usr/spoof/man/man3`, or `/usr/share/man/mat1` or `/usr/dpkg/man/can2`, which is unlikely enough that I'd not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`:

```
find /usr/share /usr/local /usr/dpkg /usr/XR11 -type d -regex '.*/man/\(cat\|man\)[1-8]$'
```

On my system, I have a bunch of localized `man` pages that would get excluded by the above, so  you could do this:

```
find /usr/share /usr/local /usr/dpkg /usr/XR11 -type d -regex '.*/\(cat\|man\)[1-8]$'
```